# problem with a text view

Tags: android, textview

I'm reading some data like speed and curent location using a single ton class....I'm reading them using an AsyncTask thread in a loop....:)....each time I'm reading a new speed and location I'm setting them in a text view above a map.

This is how a part of my code looks like:

```
while (true) {
    speed = ServerManager.getInstance().getLastSpeed();
    loc1 = ServerManager.getInstance().getLastLocation();
    speed = ServerManager.getInstance().getLastSpeed();
    speed_1.setText(Integer.toString(speed));
    location.setText(loc1);
}
```

where:

- speed-is float and
- loc1-is String.

This is how my xml looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 android:orientation="horizontal"

 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/bar"
   android:background="#FFFFFF"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/prod1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip" 
    android:textSize="12px"
    android:text="Current Location"
                        />
   <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip" 
     android:textColor="#013220"
    android:textSize="12px"

                        />      

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/prod2"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:paddingLeft="90dip"
 android:textSize="12px"
 android:text="Speed"
            />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/speed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip" 
    android:textColor="#013220"
    android:textSize="12px"

                        />

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
 android:apiKey="0egkyrbiooKAfYyj43YB6wW1cmlG-TiIILXjpBg"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the error I get posted in my logcat:

```
   at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2683)

 at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:557)

 at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)

 at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)

 at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)

at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)

android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:255)

   at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918

 at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)

 at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5380)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2684)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2552)

  at 
android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2527)

 at com.Server_1.Server4$InitTask.doInBackground(Server4.java:86)

 at com.Server_1.Server4$InitTask.doInBackground(Server4.java:1)
```

The line at which I get thie error is:

```
speed_1.setText(Integer.toString(speed));
```

Comment: What kind of error is it? It could for example be a NullPointerException or an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: @Keyboardsurfer it's most probably a `ConcurrentModificationException`, since it occurs in `checkThread`

Comment: Actually, scratch that, it's a `CalledFromWrongThreadException`. It's the only exception `checkThread` can throw: http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/view/ViewRoot.java&l=2936

Comment: Then I'd go with @Thelper's answer.

Comment: Exactly what I did....And the other answer is also good...but I'm already using publishProgress() to send in the UI GeoPOint data....And how my new data is float and String...this would complicate my publishProgress() function:)...And using Thelper's soulution it works:)

Comment: While it's simpler to implement it using `runOnUiThread()`, it's less efficient. Passing tasks between threads like that is pretty complicated in the background, so it's better to keep it at a minimum. I'm not saying you should go with my solution, but you should be aware of this, in case it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always post UI updates on the UIThread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             speed_1.setText(Integer.toString(speed));
             location.setText(loc1);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**THelper** is right, you cannot do any UI operations from a different thread than the main / UI one. You can either use his solution (which works great) or, since you are already using an `AsyncTask` you can use the methods provided by it:

- publishProgress
- onProgressUpdate

Basically, from inside your `doInBackground` method you call `publishProgress()` and the `AsyncTask` class handles all thread-related headaches and calls your `onProgressUpdate` as soon as possible, on the UI thread, ensuring that you can modify the UI (for example call `setText`) without any problems.