# onClick Listener Code doesn't show Toasts

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a simple layout employing 3 buttons. I have a listener on the first button. It gets called as expected on a click. The listener checks a few things, possible downloads a few files, then starts another activity.

During the file download, I'd like to inform the user that a download is going on. I tried the usual suspects, but I saw that using a ProgressBar would be alot of code. So I tried something smaller: I used a Toast to display a message, then disable the 3 buttons for the download duration. This is the code:

```
int version_pre = getCurrentVersion();

//Check files on remote server
String URL = Data._URL + "/" + Data.OWNER + "/version";
if(!this.downloadFile(URL, "version")) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Download der Dateien fehlgeschlagen. Fahre mit lokaler Version fort.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

int version_post = getCurrentVersion();
if(version_pre != version_post) { //Neu Dateien besorgen
  Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Prospekt);
  b1.setEnabled(false);
  b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Einheitenumrechner);
  b1.setEnabled(false);
  b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Sonstiges);
  b1.setEnabled(false);

  Toast.makeText(this, "Aktualisierung der Dateien wird gestartet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  if(!fetchAllFiles()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Download der Dateien fehlgeschlagen. Fahre mit lokaler Version fort.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Prospekt);
  b1.setEnabled(true);
  b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Einheitenumrechner);
  b1.setEnabled(true);
  b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Sonstiges);
  b1.setEnabled(true);
}

return "";
```

The problem is this: Even when debugging, I cannot see that any of the GUI changing mechanisms actually do anything. Disabling the buttons should grey them out. It doesn't. Calling the Toast.maketext().show() should display a message. It doesn't.

I suspect that this might be expected behaviour as it concerns multiple mechanisms. Is there a restriction as to what I can call in an action listener that will change the UI? Do I need to call a refresh() kinda method when changing the UI while in a Listener?

Thanks.

Comment: So you are saying that all of the above code is in a button onClick listener?  I am a little unclear as to where the above code resides (in which member and in what thread?)

Comment: This code gets called by the listener before starting the target activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `.show()` to the lines where you are calling Toast, otherwise you are just creating the message without displaying it.

For listeners, make sure that you run all GUI changes (other than Toast messages) on the UI thread (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250673/problem-with-a-text-view))

Comment: The link explained why I had the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
Toast.makeText(activityname.this, "Download der Dateien fehlgeschlagen. Fahre mit lokaler Version fort.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see where you are actually setting the onClickListener, after you have a reference to your button. It should go something like this:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {                   
                Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }               
        });
```

Also, you are using the same object reference b1 for different buttons, so only the last one will work.

Comment: The onClick listener is set statically, during design time in layout.xml.

Comment: Usually, using the same reference to call methods of different objects is not a problem. Are you sure it is with Android?